# Screen width in Windows Phone 8 applications

Tags: windows-phone-8

Is the screen width for a Windows Phone always 480?

I found this table on the internet:

http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Introduction_to_multiple-resolution_support_on_Windows_Phone_8_apps

I'm a little bit confused about the difference between Resolution and Scaled Resolution.
Does it use the same system as in iOS devices? (Retina display is 640x960 but we use 320x480 coordinate system anyway, and it's converted to appropriate pixels by the system.)

So could I presume that on Windows Phone 8 device the width would be always 480? So can I use Canvas in my XAML and give every control hard coordinates? I just want to make a side menu: make the width of Canvas 780 (300 for side menu and 480 for the viewport).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The multiple resolutions on Windows Phone 8 are handled by automatically scaling the 480 x 800 base resolution to match the phone's display resolution. The width as far as you are concerned is 480 and then according to the phone's actual resolution, the ui will be scaled from the scaled resolution to the actual resolution.